# Higher-Order Functions with Tuples

Tags: scala

I have the following problem. I was trying to make a high-order function that accepts two parameters: the String and the function type. Function type is defined this way:

```
(String, List[String]) => List[(String, List[String])]
```

I have also defined two functions `f1` and `f2` that has the same type. Afterwards I am trying to call `myfun` with `f1` or `f2`. Here is the code:

```
object Main extends App {


def f1(t: (String,List[String])): List[(String,List[String])] = ...

def f2(t: (String,List[String])): List[(String,List[String])] =  ...

def myfun(tableName: String)(fn: (String,List[String]) => List[(String,List[String])]):  List[(String,List[String])] =
 ...

val res: List[(String,List[String])] = myfun("...")(f1)
res foreach println
val res2: List[(String,List[String])] = myfun("...")(f2)
res2 foreach println
}
```

and here is the error:

```
[error]  found   : (String, List[String]) => List[(String, List[String])]
[error]  required: (String, List[String]) => List[(String, List[String])]
[error]   val res: List[(String,List[String])] =  myfun("...")(f1)
```

I cannot understand why the compiler is complaining. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Which version of `scalac` are you using?

Comment: I am using Scala 2.9.1 Are there also different compiler versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this. Note the extra set of parenthesis surrounding the argument list to `fn`.

```
def myfun(tableName: String)
         (fn: ((String,List[String])) => List[(String,List[String])]):  List[(String,List[String])] = ...
```

Unfortunately this extra set of parenthesis is needed to distinguish

```
Function1[(String, List[String]), List[(String,List[String])]]
```

from

```
Function2[String, List[String], List[(String, List[String])]]
```

Comment: Uh, I consider the error message of scalac a bug. Is there an issue filed?

Comment: Good point. I didn't even notice the text of the scalac output. I think every person who's written scala has done this once and only once.

Comment: @ziggystar I haven't tried it, but according to this it has been fixed ≥ 2.9.1 https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5067